# Динамическая ширина изображения в слайдере (CSS)

Tags: css, slider, resize

Не могу сделать динамическую ширину изображений в слайдере веб сайта (HTML + CSS + JS). При открытии окна браузера ширина первого слайда на всю ширину окна (как и надо), но если растянуть/развернуть окно браузера, ширина изображения не меняется и последующие слайды идут с такой шириной, какая была при первоначальном открытии страницы в браузере.
Пробовал width 100%, auto, inherit делал разные вариации object-fit, но результата это не пренесло.
Буде благодарен за помощь.

```css
#slider {
  width: 100%;    
  max-width: 1920px;
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 100px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 100px);
  height: -o-calc(100vh - 100px);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;   
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#slider1 {
  width: 100%;        
  max-width: 1920px;
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 100px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 100px);
  height: -o-calc(100vh - 100px);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.slider_items {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 100px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 100px);
  height: -o-calc(100vh - 100px);
}
.slider_info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 90px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(104,204,204,.3);
  z-index: 99;
}

.slider_img {
  width: inherit;
  max-width: 1920px; 
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 100px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 100px);
  height: -o-calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div id="slider_pager"></div>

  <div id="slider1" align="center">

    <div class="slider_items">
      <img class="slider_img" src="//placehold.it/350x150"/>
      <div class="slider_info">
        <h2>Slide1 title</h2>
        <p>This is the description for slide1 <a href="#">Learn more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider_items">
      <img class="slider_img" src="//placehold.it/350x150"/>
      <div class="slider_info">
        <h2>Slide2 title</h2>
        <p>This is the description for slide2 <a href="#">Learn more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а вы вместо max-width используйте другое , скажем для img сделайте display:block; и width:100%; а высоту не указывайте - должно сработать

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/k0LL9oun/  вот примерно что должно получится - это не слайдер но размер фоток для примера

Comment: @Alexandr Покажите JS слайдера.

Answer (score 2):

[FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html) тебе в помощь, он изначально адаптивный

HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

Answer (score -7):

```
window.onresize = function(){ location.reload();}
```

и в CSS `width:100%`,если  я вас правильно понял

Comment: Вот так шедевр с `onresize`. Держи минус.

Comment: Я это даже схороню себе

Comment: @andreymal Я даже встречал подобное творчество... Правда во времена народа.ру...